# how to generate a word document in open office using java?

Tags: document, openoffice.org

### Sample code snippet to generate a word document in open office API. Could not find any in Open Office Forum or Solutions to generate the word document...

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: This question is based on whether it is possible to generate a word document in open office?????. If yes, then i need a sample code to work on it. I couldn't find any proper sample code to start working on it.